# How do I import UDL into Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I need to make code formatting for an Excel formula. I find [this link](http://blogs.msmvps.com/xldynamic/2010/09/22/formulas-made-easy/) inside which there is a ZIP file with a definition and UDL.

My problem is that the explanation for UDL is a bit blurry for me:

> and the UDL file can be imported within the UDL

How do I import UDL inside Notepad++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How do I import a UDL (User Defined Language) into Notepad++?

> **Simple Install:**
>
> - Menu -> "Language" -> "Define your language..."
>
>   This opens the "User Defined Language" dialog:
>
>   [image]
> - Click "Import" and navigate to the UDL file.
>
> **Manual Install:**
>
> - Unpack to an .xml file, if zipped;
> - If you don't have an `userDefineLang.xml` file already, copy this file into the Notepad++ Install Folder.
>
>   It should be named `userDefineLang.xml`.
>
>   Note:
>
>   - It was reported that "creating the XML file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++` on 64-bit Windows 7 didn’t add the syntax highlighting
>       to notepad++. I had to move the XML file to
>       `<user>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++` for it to work."
> - Otherwise, open both the existing and new file.
> - Select all of the new file, copy, and paste at the end of the current file.
> - This will have created a spurious `</Notepad_Plus><Notepad_plus>` pair in the middle of the file, each tag on a line by itself. Remove these two
>     consecutive lines.
> - Close Notepad++.
>
> Your Languages menu will show the newly added language at the bottom,
>   next time you launch Notepad++.

Source [How to install user defined language files](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Language_Files#How_to_install_user_defined_language_files)